# Selenium does not open page with my chrome profile [Python, chrome-webdriver]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im trying to make selenium open a chrome session with my profile, the thing is when i add the param "options" in the driver args it open chrome with my profile, but it keeps in the new tab and does not open any page, when i remove "options" it open chrome without my profile, but it open the webpage i really dont know what im doing wrong, i have this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\---\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\')
options.add_argument('-disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
#this is the problematic line                                                             here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

i think i need to add argument for open the webpage in options, but i cant find how if thats the case, thank you

Comment: why dont you just put the chrome drive in the python27 script folder then  driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: thats not the problem, the problem is when i delete "chrome_options=options" to make chrome open with my profile, and i have that exec_path because all the tutorials i have read open chrome that way, im going to test what you say, but the problem still